# I can't import ChartsModule

Tags: angular, npm, chart.js

I can't import ChartsModule in my `app.module.ts` in my angular 12 project. I tried to import it but it only shows NgChartsModule, because of it some functions of the chart are not working. Here are some error that I recived.

```
./src/app/reports/reports.component.ts:42:8-33 - Error: export 'monkeyPatchChartJsTooltip' (imported as 'monkeyPatchChartJsTooltip') was not found in 'ng2-charts' (possible exports: BaseChartDirective, NgChartsConfiguration, NgChartsModule, ThemeService, baseColors)

./src/app/reports/reports.component.ts:43:8-32 - Error: export 'monkeyPatchChartJsLegend' (imported as 'monkeyPatchChartJsLegend') was not found in 'ng2-charts' (possible exports: BaseChartDirective, NgChartsConfiguration, NgChartsModule, ThemeService, baseColors)

Error: src/app/reports/reports.component.ts:4:10 - error TS2305: Module '"ng2-charts"' has no exported member 'SingleDataSet'.

4 import { SingleDataSet, Label, monkeyPatchChartJsLegend, monkeyPatchChartJsTooltip } from 'ng2-charts';
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/reports/reports.component.ts:4:25 - error TS2305: Module '"ng2-charts"' has no exported member 'Label'.

4 import { SingleDataSet, Label, monkeyPatchChartJsLegend, monkeyPatchChartJsTooltip } from 'ng2-charts';
                          ~~~~~


Error: src/app/reports/reports.component.ts:4:32 - error TS2305: Module '"ng2-charts"' has no exported member 'monkeyPatchChartJsLegend'.

4 import { SingleDataSet, Label, monkeyPatchChartJsLegend, monkeyPatchChartJsTooltip } from 'ng2-charts';
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/reports/reports.component.ts:4:58 - error TS2305: Module '"ng2-charts"' has no exported member 'monkeyPatchChartJsTooltip'.

4 import { SingleDataSet, Label, monkeyPatchChartJsLegend, monkeyPatchChartJsTooltip } from 'ng2-charts';
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried to search from the documentation but it mentions nothing about this kind of error.
Here is the link of the documentation that I copied for this

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-pie-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
```

and

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts
```

I did all the steps mention here btw

Comment: Suspect that it is due to the installed version of ng2-charts and chart.js. Make sure you install the same version in your project as the StackBlitz link.

Comment: I did though. I just copy all the npm install thingy on the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Please check your "ChartsModule" Version in the package.json file and check whether it is supporting that or not. It might get updated.

If you wanted to use that code then you might need to downgrade or upgrade your version.

To update the version you can copy and paste the version number to your package.json file and run "npm i" to update it.

Comment: I tried to follow it but its the same i can't import the chartsmodule

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same version of chart.js that was used,
Put the below version in the package.json and run npm i , might help

`"chart.js": "^2.9.3"`

Comment: I did what u said still the same